# Set cover in 3-dimensional space

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm, np-complete

I need help with constructing an Algorithm for the following problem.

I have a set of points *G* that can "see" other points *C*. Need an algorithm to find minimal set from *G* that covers all of *C* (*G* is not necessarily part of *C*).

I have a feeling that this should be solved with dynamic programming. But I am open to any solution/ideas that can help me.

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

I may have not understood the problem fully.

The points are located on a 3d surface - with terrain heights.  The terrain might go up to a certain height between the points, making it so a point can not see the other point. As long as there is a direct line of sight the points can see each other no matter what the distance.

- if point *a* (from *G*) can see point *b* (from *C*) - and point *b* can see *d* (from *C*), then *a* can see *d*. Not sure wether this makes a difference.
- if only *a* (from *G*) can see *b* (from *C*) , we must choose *a* in order to cover all *C* - so better do that before using the greedy algorithm.

Still thinking if there are any other differences in light of the new information.

Comment: What does the word "see" mean here?

Comment: Are the points located on a 3d **plane** or are they located on a 3d **surface**?

Comment: there is a terrain that is defined x,y,z which means height , and points C,G that are defined by x,y,z which means height over terrain

Comment: How does position affect the possibility of a point to see other points? Can they see each other if they are closer than a certain distance?

Comment: no. but the terrain might go up to a certain height between them , making it so a point can not see the other point. as long as there is a direct line of sight the points can see each other no matter what the distance

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is called [Set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover). It is NP-complete.

I would use a greedy log(*n*) approximation algorithm. It picks at every step the element in (G) that covers the maximal number of points in (C) that are still not covered.

---

Most lecture notes found on Internet show only the approximation algorithm described above.

It is very difficult to do much better than the algorithm above, as has been proved by Lund & Yannakakis (1994). You can find the reference inside the wikipedia article.

You can also use the equivalent integer linear problem formulation of the set cover problem. But again you get a log(n) approximation algorithm.

There are other approximation algotihms, but most of them are in research papers, so that their description is not really easy to understand. You can find them just googling "approximation algorithms set cover"

---

I don't know if there is a rule of thumb to know if a problem is NP-complete or is a variant of a known problem ti which exist solutions using, say, dynamic programming. But I have posted a question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1859/rule-of-thumb-to-know-if-a-problem-could-be-np-complete).

---

About the case when only *a* (from *G*) can see *b* (from *C*), the greedy algorithm would pick *a* anyway, because it stops only when all the points from *C* are seen. The order in which the algorithm chooses the points does not change the solution.

---

The fact that if point *a* (from *G*) can see point *b* (from *C*) - and point *b* can see *d* (from *C*), then a can see *d*, does not permit the problem to be modeled ad a [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph). Planar graphs have better approximation algorithms for your problem, better than the greedy algorithm.

Comment: Thank you! 1) i read the wiki article the Low-frequency systems algorithms, does not match my case. are there any other approximation algorithms? 2) any tips on how to find if your algorithm problems are equivalent to known problems?

Comment: Hi! I have updated my answer, adding ansers to your comments! See above.

Comment: in the end I thought about this solution. choose the point from C which has the least amount of guards (if one guard - must choose that point anyway..) if a there are a few guards choose the one the covers more points in C.  now i need to show examples where this algorithm is worse then the optimal - and try to prove the approximation factor (or that it is infinity..)

Comment: I think that you should ask a new question. Also condider asking it on http://cs.stackexchange.com/